# Move MSSQL Server to another Server

Tags: sql-server, backup, sql, migration

So I'm about to move a MSSQL Server to another better hardware server.
I need to make sure I'm moving everything.
I made a small list of what I think I need to move:

Databases (ofcourse :))

MSSQL Mail Settings
MSSQL Jobs

MSSQL Maintenance plans.

MSSQL Users (System users)

My question is, There is a way to export or backup those settings and then easily restore them on the new server? instead of recreating everything.
Like, Backup entire MSSQL server settings?

Hard disk / Operation System Clone is not an option for me.

Comment: Here's a better idea: Install a proper hypervisor on the new server (Hyper-V, ESXi, etc). Then perform a physical to virtual conversion of the SQL Server and host the SQL Server virtual machine on the hypervisor host. You can then allocate the needed resources to the virtual machine and never have to worry about "migrating" the SQL Server configuration, settings, users, etc. ever again. You can scale it up or down, move it to a different hypervisor host, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Thank you, I also found a solution:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/514dcabb-cb9a-4ece-a3d0-f4ae141b6e30/extract-configuration-of-another-copy-sqlserver?forum=sqlservermigration
http://yrushka.com/index.php/sql-server/database-recovery/sql-server-migration-from-one-server-to-another-detailed-checklist/

Answer (score -1):

I would check out [Http://Dbatools.io](http://dbatools.io)

Like Copy-SqlDatabases, Start-SqlMigration currently supports migrating via backup/restore and detach/attach.

> **Migrated objects**
>
> - All user databases. Use -NoDatabases to skip.
> - All logins. Use -NoLogins to skip.
> - All database mail objects. Use -NoDatabaseMail
> - All credentials. Use -NoCredentials to skip.
> - All objects within the Job Server (SQL Agent). Use -NoJobServer to skip.
> - All linked servers. Use -NoLinkedServers to skip.
> - All groups and servers within Central Management Server. Use -NoCentralManagementServer to skip.
> - All SQL Server configuration objects (everything in sp_configure). Use -NoSpConfigure to skip.
> - All user objects in system databases. Use -NoSysDbUserObjects to skip.
> - All system triggers. Use -NoSystemTriggers to skip.
> - All system backup devices. Use -NoBackupDevices to skip.
> - All Audits. Use -NoAudits to skip.
> - All Endpoints. Use -NoEndpoints to skip.
> - All Extended Events. Use -NoExtendedEvents to skip.
> - All Policy Management objects. Use -NoPolicyManagement to skip.
> - All Resource Governor objects. Use -NoResourceGovernor to skip.
> - All Server Audit Specifications. Use -NoServerAuditSpecifications to skip.
> - All Custom Errors (User Defined Messages). Use -NoCustomErrors to skip.

***Disclaimer:  I do not work for dbatools.io Just a really big fan.  I have done many migrations with this tool and it handles 100% of the migration!***

Comment: Why the down vote?